# Formatting Dates in R - Cleaning my Data so That it Only Includes Certain Months of the Year

Tags: r

Thank you for viewing this post first and foremost. I am struggling with formatting some dates with corresponding values in R. I am using a dataset that includes monthly snowfall (VALUE) with its respective year/month (month).

Currently, I have it to where it includes all months of the year, but I would like to limit it down to just including October-March. I am using `library(dplyr)` to help with the cleaning. Currently, I have the following code:

```
snow <- 
  snoworig %>% pivot_longer(cols = c(JUL:JUN)) %>% 
  select(SEASON, name, value) %>% 
  rename(MONTH = "name", VALUE = "value") %>% tidyr::unite("month", 1:2, sep = " ")
```

When running `dput(head(snoworig,10))`, I get the following:

```
structure(list(SEASON = c("1869-70", "1870-71", "1871-72", "1872-73", 
"1873-74", "1874-75", "1875-76", "1876-77", "1877-78", "1878-79"
), JUL = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), AUG = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), SEP = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), OCT = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0), NOV = c(0, 0, 0.3, 3.5, 2, 0, 0, 
0.1, 0, 0.1), DEC = c(5.3, 3, 3.9, 27, 9.3, 10, 0.5, 12.4, 0, 
5.5), JAN = c(1.1, 15.9, 1.8, 10.6, 6.6, 14.5, 1.5, 20.5, 6.1, 
17.3), FEB = c(9.3, 12.1, 3, 18.8, 19, 4.5, 12.5, 0.4, 2, 11.3
), MAR = c(9.6, 0.1, 5.1, 0.4, 0, 15.3, 3.8, 6.5, 0, 1.5), APR = c(2.5, 
2, 0, 0, 0, 13.5, 0, 0, 0, 0), MAY = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0), JUN = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), TOTAL = c(27.8, 
33.1, 14.1, 60.3, 36.9, 57.8, 18.3, 40.4, 8.1, 35.7)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Like I said, I am only wanting now to consider the months October-March. Is this a simple fix with the code I currently have, or should I be interested in starting from scratch (with the data from the original excel file)?

All help is appreciated, and if you have further questions please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Can you use `dput(head(snoworig, 10))` to share some of the `snoworig` object?

Comment: @JoshGray sure, I just updated my post. Let me know if anything else interests you! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`base::grepl()` does this nicely (`?grepl`):

```
snow %>% 
    filter(grepl("OCT|NOV|DEC|JAN|FEB|MAR", month))

# A tibble: 60 × 2
   month       VALUE
   <chr>       <dbl>
 1 1869-70 OCT   0  
 2 1869-70 NOV   0  
 3 1869-70 DEC   5.3
 4 1869-70 JAN   1.1
 5 1869-70 FEB   9.3
 6 1869-70 MAR   9.6
 7 1870-71 OCT   0  
 8 1870-71 NOV   0  
 9 1870-71 DEC   3  
10 1870-71 JAN  15.9
# … with 50 more rows
```

Comment: Okay, so where exactly will these lines of code be placed in my original? Thank you again for the help. @JoshGray

Comment: If you want `snow` to contain the filtered data, you could simply append to the end of your code like this `snow <- snoworig %>% pivot_longer(cols = c(JUL:JUN)) %>% select(SEASON, name, value) %>% rename(MONTH = "name", VALUE = "value") %>% tidyr::unite("month", 1:2, sep = " ") %>% filter(grepl("OCT|NOV|DEC|JAN|FEB|MAR", month))`

Comment: Never mind, I got it! Thank you so much!